# PointerDownThemeAnimation application stops WP8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm confused why my app is closing, I have added the PointerDownThemeAnimation and it works fine but only one time, when I try to click it again the aplication stops. Why?
Here is my code:

```
private void staryrynek1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pointerDownStoryboard.Begin();
}

private void staryrynek(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pointerUpStoryboard.Begin();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(StaryRynek));
}
```

and

```
<Grid x:Name="staryrynek_grid" Margin="10,92,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" PointerPressed="staryrynek1" PointerReleased="staryrynek">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="pointerDownStoryboard">
                <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="staryrynek_grid" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="pointerUpStoryboard">
                <PointerUpThemeAnimation TargetName="staryrynek_grid" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.495"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" FontSize="29.333" Text="Stary Rynek"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I think you have wrongly tagged your question - probably you are using WP8.1 Runtime (Windows Store Apps). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Romasz I think thats right

Comment: As I've tried your code, you are getting an exception conected with PlaneProjection. Have you tried to follow [guidelines at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj649432.aspx) and [some information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.pointerdownthemeanimation.aspx)?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Both answers didn't work for me... Still throwing NullReferenceException...

Comment: It seems that this is bug in XAML for Windows Phone: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/adf98a1f-13d4-4600-a4b4-ee1555d9bace/pointerdownthemeanimation-crashing?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 2):

I think you found a genuine bug. Here's the workaround.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="PointerDownStory">
            <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="MyRectangle" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="PointerUpStory">
            <PointerUpThemeAnimation TargetName="MyRectangle" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle"
               PointerPressed="Grid_PointerPressed"
               PointerReleased="Grid_PointerReleased" />
</Grid>
```

Code-behind

```
private void Grid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyRectangle.Projection = new PlaneProjection();
    PointerDownStory.Begin();
}

private void Grid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerUpStory.Begin();
}
```

It's the `this.MyRectangle.Projection = new PlaneProjection();` line you should notice. It's the only real change from your original code. Seems like the `PointerUpThemeAnimation` inadvertently destroys the `PlaneProjection`. This would have been okay if the `PointerDownThemeAnimation` would re-create it.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have a [blog post](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/07/08/Tilt-animation-for-Windows-Phone-Runtime.aspx) on how you can get tilt for "normal" items. What are you are trying to do can be achieved, but there is a problem in which the animation is still active. You need to stop the animation before playing it.

```
private void staryrynek1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pointerDownStoryboard.Stop();
    pointerDownStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

The post has a total of three ways to enable tilt plus a working sample to download